# VS2010, column width of watch window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, column-width, watch-window

I can't see values of variables in my Watch window. I can see the variable names. I believe it's because the column width for variable name column is very wide. This problem exists for all watch windows. Quick Watch and Local shows values fine.

I tried reset the settings using Tools->Import and Export Settings but to no effect.

Any ideas apart from a reinstall of VS2010?

Comment: Unfortunately the Visual Studio team doesn't find this to be important and has closed the UserVoice case: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/3558071-remember-quickwatch-window-column-sizes

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to resize them yourself by dragging the tickmark (the line that seperates each two column header), or double clicking it so that it would auto size? It might be hard to see it, if someone pushed it all the way to the right, but trust that it's there :)